# Elasticsearch Convert string field to date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a type 'document'. It has a field of type string with the name 'date' and the entries are of the format "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a".

I wish to convert the data type of this field from string to date which isn't possible directly.
So, I have modified the mapping to add a new field 'posted' of type 'date' and format. I now need to copy the value from the date field to the posted field after changing it into a date object. I tried the following update query

```
POST /my-index/document/_update_by_query
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "script": "ctx._source['posted'] = new Date().parse(\"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a\",ctx._source['date'])"
}
```

But it gives me this error,

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to create a `Date` type in your script, you just assign the value to the `posted` field, Elasticsearch will do the rest when the index operation happens.

You also need to change the structure of your script

```
"script": {
  "inline": "ctx._source['posted'] = ctx._source.foo"
}
```

Comment: "script": "ctx._source['posted'] = ctx._source['date']" Still gives me the same error

Comment: hit sent to early, also fixed the script

Comment: "script": "ctx._source['posted'] = ctx._source.date" still gave the same error